# Kafka Consumer Test cases Problem using Mockito and testng

Tags: testing, apache-kafka, mocking, mockito, testng

I have written a Service that calls and starts up multiple Kafka Consumers. So I have to write a test case for the complete scenario using testing and mockito. Starting the service starts all the consumers. I am mocking the service but the service doesn't start the consumers. It stops without throwing any error.

Cant we start Kafka COnsumers with @mock?

Edit:
Consumerservice.class

```
class Consumerservice
{  
@Autowired 
public ProducerService producerService;

@Autowired
HandleFactory  handlefactory;

public void execute(){
//Start all consumers code
}
}
```

TestCase.class

```
class testConsumer
{
@Mock
Consumerservice consumerservice;
    @Mock
    ProducerService  producerService ;

    @Test
    void test1()
    {

    consumerservice.execute();


    //when and assert statement on producerService

    }
    }
```

The consumerservice.execute(); line don't shows any log or runs or throws any errors. How to know if it is working or not.

Comment: Can you please share the code snippet for the service and then the test ?

Comment: @ForeverLearner check I have edited